# Extract customer_id that have been active on certain platforms

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to extract the following information:

1. **Distinct** `Customer_ids` that have been active on **platform A and B**
2. **Distinct** `Customer_ids` that have been active on neither platform A and B (i.e. customers who have been active on any other platform other than A and B)

Main table

```
date          customer_id  platform
2019-01-01    1            A
2019-01-01    1            B
2019-01-01    2            A
2019-01-01    2            B
2019-01-01    3            A
2019-01-01    4            A
2019-01-01    4            B
2019-01-01    5            C
2019-01-01    6            D
```

Output table 1

```
Date         customerID_active_both_platforms
2019-01-01      1
2019-01-01      2
2019-01-01      4
```

Output table 2

```
Date         customerID_active_neither_platforms
2019-01-01      5
2019-01-01      6
```

Answer (score 0):

You may handle this using conditional aggregation.  For the first requirement of customers with both platforms A and B:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    customer_id AS customerID_active_both_platforms
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    platform IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY
    Date,
    customer_id
HAVING
    MIN(platform) <> MAX(platform);
```

For the second requirement, customers having neither platform A nor B:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    customer_id AS customerID_active_neither_platforms
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Date,
    customer_id
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN platform IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: I get no results for both

Comment: Your data suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this information *per customer*, then use two levels of aggregation -- first by customer/date and then by customer:

```
select date,
       sum( is_a * is_b ) as num_ab,
       sum( (1 - is_a) * (1 - is-b) ) as num_not_ab
from (select customer, date,
             max(case when platform = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as is_a,
             max(case when platform = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as is_b,
             max(case when platform not in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) as is_not_ab
      from t
      group by customer, date
     ) t
from t
group by date;
```

Of course, you can filter with a `where` clause to get customers that only meet one or the other condition.

Comment: Instead of summing all customer_id's for num_ab - how can I show all customer_id's that meet num_ab criteria (being both on platform A and B)

Comment: You would put `where is_a = 1 and is_b = 1` in the outer query, remove the `group by` and select the columns you want.